# Qual seria o melhor "highlight" para a tag Angular?

Tags: debate, tag-específica, syntax-highlighting

Hoje me deparei que a tag [angular](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) (não confundir com [angularjs](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs)) não tem "highlight" pros códigos, creio que talvez seria o mesmo da tag [typescript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript), apesar de ter HTML as vezes na postagem que podem estar a parte do template, sendo exibidos para melhor explicação.

Por exemplo, hoje respondi a uma pergunta que só tinha a tag angular:

> [image: post tag angular sem highlight]

Mas se tivesse a tag typescript ficaria assim provavelmente:

> [image: post tag angular com highlight]

---

Neste caso queria discutir com a comunidade o que acham que seria melhor:

1. Colocar o hightlight do TypeScript para Angular
2. Editar pergunta a pergunta (quando formos responder) e colocar a tag [typescript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript) na edição, quando for necessário

Qualquer sugestão é bem vinda!

Comment: TypeScript usa o realçador de JS, o sistema não tem realçador específico. Sendo assim não tem muito o que escolher...

Comment: @bfavaretto entendo, então vou usar `<!-- language: lang-javascript -->` por enquanto

Comment: Em teoria não precisa, a tag angularjs já está configurada como JS.

Comment: Ah, errei de tag, peraí

Comment: @bfavaretto kkkkkkkkkk, agora entendi, pois é AngularJS e Angular ainda vão nos confundir muito xD

Comment: A que está configurada é angularjs, não angular. Fiz uma mudança, definindo a sintaxe de angular como "default". O resultado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/292223/74) parece razoável.

Comment: @bfavaretto parece que afetou os HTML do template do Angular, acho que antes não tinha o realce no ngIf e ngFor, se for isso mesmo parece promissor :D ... por que geralmente são os atributos do Angular em HTML que interessam neste tipo de pergunta.

Comment: É, o default pega HTML também. Até decorators ele realçou, eu não esperava.